# Computing codebooks in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

There are questions referring to the same incomprehensible exception, but I would like to ask it clearly with a minimal example.

I have the following code:

- load all the SIFT descriptors from files;
- normalize the descriptors such as they are CV_32F;

then:

- initialize a BowTrainer (code based on an example found on-line):

  ```
  TermCriteria tc(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER,100,0.001);
  int retries=1;
  int flags=KMEANS_PP_CENTERS;
  BOWKMeansTrainer bow_trainer(dictionary_size, tc, retries, flags);
  ```

and finally:

```
   vocabulary = bow_trainer.cluster(training_descriptors);
```

where `training_descriptors` is a `1218772 * 128` CV_32F matrix containing 0,1 normalized SIFT descriptors.

Unfortunately `cluster` generates an exception saying:

`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (data.dims <= 2 && type == CV_32F && K > 0) in kmeans, file /Users/u/Downloads/OpenCV-2.4.4/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 2686`

The type of the matrix is correct, i.e., `CV_32F` and I do not understand whose data.dims should be <=2 and why it looks like K <= 0.

Answer (score 0):

By coincidence I just got this same error. In my case it was because the descriptors Mat had zero elements in it. I suspect this is what the data.dims <= 2 refers to.

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (data.dims <= 2 && type == CV_32F && K > 0) in kmeans, file /home/ubuntu/opencv-2.4.5/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 2686
```

Did you check that your array of descriptors is not empty?

Comment: Hi, I solved this problem but do not remember what I did. In my case that was the case, there were several descriptors.